# PHP page not loading with SQL statement included

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my page won't load when I have the following php code in it... but when I validate the SQL stmt in my editor, it returns results (1 row) fine. I've tried debugging with the F12 Chrome thing, but the console doesnt show any errors outside of some CSS stuff. I don't really know how to use it to a further extent.

Any initial thoughts?

page:
http://www.runic-paradise.com/editinfo.php

Code that kills the page when it's present:

```
// GET NEWS FROM DB
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Content, Reference FROM site WHERE Reference='Rules'");
```

Surrounding
Code:

```
        <form id="newsform" name="newsform" action="editinfo.php?step=2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Server Rules</h4>
        <textarea class="editor" rows="4" style="width:50%;" name="Content" id="postbody">
<?php
 //UPDATE DB IF NECESSARY
if($_GET['step'] == 2) {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE site SET Content='$_POST[Content]' WHERE Reference='Rules'");
}
// GET NEWS FROM DB
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Content, Reference FROM site WHERE Reference='Rules'");
var_dump($mysqli->error);
echo $result['Content'];
$mysqli->close();

?>
        </textarea>

        <!-- hidden inputs -->
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />

        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the php page and run again.

Comment: Use mysqli_error() to see what is causing error

Comment: The source code of your page states this `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in <b>/home/content/60/11957760/html/runicparadise/editinfo.php</b> on line <b>117</b>`

Comment: @asprin - done, no extra messages

Comment: @asprin - that seems to be it... when I // out the echo (//echo $result['Content'];)  ... it loads OK.   But then how do I access data in $result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not extracting the data correct.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Content, Reference FROM site WHERE Reference='Rules'");
$result = $result->fetch_assoc(); // <-- here
echo $result['Content'];
```

you need to retrieve the result as an array before you can treat the result as an array.

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly code not protected from any SQL injections. Do not pass user input data to SQL directly.

May be error in:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in <b>/home/content/60/11957760/html/runicparadise/editinfo.php</b> on line <b>117</b><br />
```

Comment: thanks :) have updated my UPDATE as      $contents = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Content']); 
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE site SET Content='$contents' WHERE Reference='Rules'");

Comment: It is better, but I suggest you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).